# Content will not float the the right of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm just playing around with creating a website, excuse the messy code, quite new to this game.

Basically I'm trying to section a website with each sections content either going to the left or right, alternating. 
As you can see I've managed to do the one to the left (Section2), however I can't seem to do the one on the right (Section3). The nav bar is also fixed but isn't showing on the JSFiddle. I'm also wondering why my text displays fine on my 1920x1080 monitor, but on my 1366x768 laptop, it overflows out of the div, bear in mind that the backgrounds of each section will be will eventually be an image, so I can't repeat it.

I've uploaded a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jw5du15v/) as I was getting confused with what I had to do to upload code here, hope it is not a problem.

I appreciate your help, and again sorry for the incredible messy code!

```
<section id="screen1">
    <div class="hLogo">Title</div>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">3</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">4</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">5</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">6</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <img class="ad" src="css/asc.jpg" />
    </nav>
</section>
<section id="screen2">
    <div class="content left nobg">
        <div class="scrTitle">About</div>
        <p class="scrContent">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum eros nisi, consequat sit amet sodales vitae, molestie eu elit. Nullam gravida laoreet nulla sit amet pretium. Vivamus nisi est, imperdiet a venenatis vel, porttitor vitae dui. Vivamus laoreet tortor in diam interdum, ac dapibus ante pretium. Vivamus gravida leo sit amet placerat lobortis. Sed odio arcu, tempus non gravida ut, egestas ut velit. Ut vitae enim fringilla, consequat massa quis, interdum sem. Donec vel sollicitudin urna. Suspendisse eget mi neque. Phasellus adipiscing nunc vitae nulla molestie tempor. Curabitur porttitor pretium augue, sit amet ornare metus.</p>
    </div>
</section>
<section id="screen3">
    <div class="content right nobg">
        <div class="scrTitle">About</div>
        <p class="scrContent">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum eros nisi, consequat sit amet sodales vitae, molestie eu elit. Nullam gravida laoreet nulla sit amet pretium. Vivamus nisi est, imperdiet a venenatis vel, porttitor vitae dui. Vivamus laoreet tortor in diam interdum, ac dapibus ante pretium. Vivamus gravida leo sit amet placerat lobortis. Sed odio arcu, tempus non gravida ut, egestas ut velit. Ut vitae enim fringilla, consequat massa quis, interdum sem. Donec vel sollicitudin urna. Suspendisse eget mi neque. Phasellus adipiscing nunc vitae nulla molestie tempor. Curabitur porttitor pretium augue, sit amet ornare metus.</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/kiranm/jw5du15v/3/ ?

Comment: @Viroe - I think your jsFiddle could be broken. You've got script tags in the JS section and no reference to jQuery.

Comment: I think you need the column like structure just like in the news papers. right?

Comment: @Kiran Almost there! I'm looking for the title and the content on the left for section2, and the title and the content on the right for section 3.

Comment: @BlankHead Not really like that, I will make the content area wider, I was just playing around with it, sorry.

Comment: @viroe See my answer, is that what you was looking for? view the jsfiddle

Comment: @Stefan Oops I forgot! The JS is only the navigation, I don't really need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix your problem with section 3 not going to the right, You can just add this bit of code to your CSS:

```
.scrContent2 {
    font-size: 75%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 20%;
    float: right;
 }
```

This means that your HTML will need changing for section 3 as follows:

```
<p class="scrContent2">
```

Here is a jsfiddle of this.. http://jsfiddle.net/jw5du15v/5/

Comment: Exactly what i'm looking for! Thanks, I don't suppose you would be able to help me with my overflowing text at different resolutions? Is it possible to make the text depending on resolution other than media queries?

Comment: No problem, and uhmm, I'm not too sure about that, I'll take a look now, see if I can help

Comment: I Guess this is a start, I've put a wrapper around your title & text with min and max properties, preventing the text going 'passed' the title on different resolutions/zooming in and out - http://jsfiddle.net/jw5du15v/9/

Comment: @Viroe, for overflowing text just add this to your `css` : `#screen2,#screen3{display: table;}`. This will wrap all your text inside the `div`. And for the `font-size`, I suggest to use `media-queries`. Here's the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jw5du15v/10/

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kiranm/jw5du15v/3/)**

**CSS:**

```
.right {
    margin-right: 10%;
    text-align:right;
    float:right;
}
.left {
    margin-left: 10%;
    float: left;
    text-align:left:
}
```

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="content nobg">
            <div class="scrTitle left">About</div>
            <p class="scrContent right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum eros nisi, consequat sit amet sodales vitae, molestie eu elit. Nullam gravida laoreet nulla sit amet pretium. Vivamus nisi est, imperdiet a venenatis vel, porttitor vitae dui. Vivamus laoreet tortor in diam interdum, ac dapibus ante pretium. Vivamus gravida leo sit amet placerat lobortis. Sed odio arcu, tempus non gravida ut, egestas ut velit. Ut vitae enim fringilla, consequat massa quis, interdum sem. Donec vel sollicitudin urna. Suspendisse eget mi neque. Phasellus adipiscing nunc vitae nulla molestie tempor. Curabitur porttitor pretium augue, sit amet ornare metus.</p>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I need both title and content on the same sides

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to float your webpages to left and Right.

Try this

```
.content left nobg {

    float:left;
}

.content right nobg {

    float:right;
 }
```